# How exactly do we get that for every $n>kN$ we have $|S_n-T|<\epsilon$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence such that $a_n\to 0$ and let $k$ be a natural number such that $k>1$.
> Let $b_1=a_1+\dots+a_k$ and $b_{n+1}=a_{kn+1}+a_{kn+2}+\dots+a_{k(n+1)}$ for every $n\geq 1$.
> Prove that if $\sum b_n$ converges then $\sum a_n$ converges.

The proof:

Let $$T_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n} b_i,S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i$$ and let $T_n\to T$.
Let $\epsilon>0$. We have $$S_{kn}=\sum_{i=1}^{kn}a_i=\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i=T_n\to T$$ and therefore there exists an $N_0$ such that $|S_{kn}-T|<\epsilon$ for every $n>N_0$.

We have $$S_{kn+1}=T_n+a_{kn+1}\to T+0=T$$ and therefore there exists an $N_1$ such that $|S_{kn+1}-T|<\epsilon$ for every $n>N_1$.

We have $$S_{kn+2}=T_n+a_{kn+1}+a_{kn+2}\to T+0=T$$ and therefore there exists an $N_2$ such that $|S_{kn+2}-T|<\epsilon$ for every $n>N_2$.

...

We have $$S_{kn+(k-1)}=T_n+\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}a_{kn+i}\to T+0=T$$ and therefore there exists an $N_{k-1}$ such that $|S_{kn+(k-1)}-T|<\epsilon$ for every $n>N_{k-1}$
(we are given that $a_n\to 0$ and therefore for every $i=1,...,k-1$ we have $a_{kn+i}\to 0$).
But for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists an $i\in\{0,1,...,k-1\}$ and an $n_0$ such that $n=kn_0+i$ and therefore the sequences $$(S_{kn}),(S_{kn+1}),...,(S_{kn+(k-1)})$$ cover the sequence $(S_k)$. Define $N=\max\{N_0,N_1,...,N_{k-1}\}$ and we get that for every $n>kN$ we have $|S_n-T|<\epsilon$ and therefore $S_n\to T$ and in particular, the series $\sum a_n$ converges.

How exactly do we get that for every $n>kN$ we have $|S_n-T|<\epsilon$?

Answer (score 1):

You have proved the following:

> **Proposition.** For any $\epsilon>0$ and any $j\in\{0,\cdots,k-1\}$, there exists $N_j$, s.t. $n>N_j\implies|S_{kn+j}-T|<\epsilon$.

Now let $\epsilon>0$ be any positive number and let $N=\max_{j=0,\cdots,k-1}\{N_j\}$ where $N_j$ is given by the proposition above. For any $n>kN$, write $n=km+r$, where $r$ is the remainder of $n$ divided by $k$, so that $0\leq r<k$ and $m>kN/k=N\geq N_r$. Hence, by the proposition above, $m>N_r\implies |S_{km+r}-T|<\epsilon\implies|S_n-T|>\epsilon$.

Answer (score -1):

Let $S_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}$ and $T_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_{i}$.
Note that $S_{kn}=T_{n}$ for all $n\geq1$.
Suppose that $\sum b_n$ converges.
We go to show that $(S_{n})$
is a Cauchy sequence. Let $\varepsilon>0$ be arbitrary. Choose $N_{1}$
such that $|a_{n}|\leq\frac{\varepsilon}{k}$ whenever $n\geq N_{1}$
(This is possible because $a_{n}\rightarrow0$). Since $(T_{n})$
converges, we can choose $N_{2}$ such that $|T_{m}-T_{n}|<\varepsilon$
whenever $m,n\geq N_{2}$. Let $N=\max(N_{1},kN_{2})$. Let $m,n\geq N$
be arbitrary. There exist integers $l_{1},l_{2}$ such that $l_{1}k\leq m<(l_{1}+1)k$
and $l_{2}k\leq n<(l_{2}+1)k$. Clearly $l_{1},l_{2}\geq N_{2}$.
(For, if $l_{1}<N_{2}$, then $m<(l_{1}+1)k\leq N_{2}k\leq N$, contradicting
to the condition that $m\geq N$). We have estimation:
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \left|S_{m}-S_{n}\right|\\
 & \leq & \left|S_{m}-S_{l_{1}k}\right|+\left|S_{l_{1}k}-S_{l_{2}k}\right|+\left|S_{l_{2}k}-S_{n}\right|\\
 & \leq & \left\{ |a_{l_{1}k+1}|+\ldots+|a_{m}|\right\} +\left|T_{l_{1}}-T_{l_{2}}\right|+\left\{ |a_{l_{2}k+1}|+\ldots+|a_{n}|\right\} \\
 & \leq & \frac{\varepsilon}{k}(m-l_{1}k)+\varepsilon+\frac{\varepsilon}{k}(n-l_{2}k)\\
 & \leq & 3\varepsilon.
\end{eqnarray*}
This show that $(S_{n})$ is a Cauchy sequence and hence it converges.